# Calculate Total Event Attendees

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am attempting to determine the total number of people who attended events hosted by a specific group.

I want to display the total number of attendees, the maximum attendance allowed, the event title, event date, and the event contact person.  I tried the following query in different ways, but keep getting the "enter paramenter value" dialog box in MS Access 2007.  What do I need to change?

```
SELECT sum(eventAttendance.attended) AS attendanceTotal, events.max, events.title, events.date, events.eventContact, events.unit
    FROM (client INNER JOIN eventAttendance ON client.clientID=eventAttendance.clientID) INNER JOIN events ON eventAttendance.ID=events.id
    WHERE events.unit='CTL'and eventAttendance.attended = 'yes'
    GROUP BY attendanceTotal, events.max, events.title, events.date, events.eventContact, events.unit;
```

Thank you.

[Table Relationships](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGTbN.jpg)

Comment: You must have a space before the word `and` in this section: `events.unit='CTL'and`

Comment: What does the parameter box ask for?  `attendanceTotal`?  Or `'CTL'and`?

Comment: @HansUp:  the box prompts for attendanceTotal.

Comment: That makes sense.  Something else is more troubling: your query attempts `sum(eventAttendance.attended)`, but the WHERE clause suggests that is a text field (eventAttendance.attended = 'yes').  So what do you expect to get as the Sum of a text field?  Do you want Count() instead?  Is eventAttendance.attended actually a Yes/No or numeric field type?

Comment: Edit your question to show us brief samples of the relevant fields from the 3 tables, and show us what you want as the output from the query.

Comment: Maybe I am using the wrong function?  I want the total number of people who registered for the event.  That would total the number of "yes"'s per event in the eventAttendance table.  eventAttendance.attended is a text field.

Comment: added link to image showing table relationships.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    events.[max],
    events.title,
    events.[date],
    events.eventContact,
    events.unit,
    Count(eventAttendance.attended) AS attendanceTotal
FROM
    (client INNER JOIN eventAttendance
    ON client.clientID=eventAttendance.clientID)
    INNER JOIN events ON eventAttendance.ID=events.id
WHERE
        events.unit='CTL'
    AND eventAttendance.attended = 'yes'
GROUP BY
    events.[max],
    events.title,
    events.[date],
    events.eventContact,
    events.unit;
```

I changed the aggregate function from Sum() to Count().  Notice the aggregate function does not get included in the GROUP BY clause --- the GROUP BY lists only the fields (or field expressions) which determine the groups, **NOT** any aggregate functions.

I also added square brackets around the field names max and date because those are both [reserved words](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueBadWord.html) --- bracketing the names reduces the risk of confusing the database engine.

**Edit**:  Your picture which shows the relationships also shows you have additional reserved words as field names.  Suggest you download Allen Browne's [Database Issue Checker Utility](http://allenbrowne.com/AppIssueChecker.html) and check your application with it.  It will warn you about reserved words and also other potential "gotcha" issues.

Comment: Thank you for reminding me about the brackets.  This is getting closer to what I want; however, the attendanceTotal is only returning a value of 1 instead of counting how many people attended the event.

Comment: I don't see what the client table contributes to this query.  It could help to show us samples of the data as a I suggested.

Comment: The clientID from the client table coincides with the clientID of the eventAttendance table.  If the client attended an event, the clientID is present and the attended field is marked "yes."
What type of samples may I provide for further assistance?

Comment: Show us brief samples of data in the relevant fields from the 3 tables, and show us what you want as the output from a query based on that data.

Comment: I actually changed it up a bit to:

 SELECT events.max, events.title, events.[date], events.eventContact, events.unit, Count(eventAttendance.eventID) AS attendanceTotal 
 FROM (client INNER JOIN eventAttendance ON client.clientID=eventAttendance.clientID) INNER JOIN events ON eventAttendance.eventID=events.id 
 WHERE events.unit='CTL' AND eventAttendance.attended = 'yes' 
 GROUP BY events.max, events.title, events.[date], events.eventContact, events.unit

This is producing what I want.  Without your help, however, I would not be this far.  Thank you!

Comment: Your working SQL is almost exactly the same as what I posted.  The only differences I can find are that you left off the square brackets from around `max`, and didn't add a semi-colon to the end of the statement.